# Jinja2 Padding and Aligning Strings

Tags: python, string, formatting, jinja2

I would like to achieve something similar to this (https://pyformat.info/#string_pad_align) in Jinja2.

In python if I want a string to always be a certain length I would do something like this:

```
'{:>10}'.format('test')
```

How can I do this in Jinja2?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found a solution! You can use the builtin filter for Jinja like so

```
{{ "%-10s" | format("test",) }}
```

Answer (score 4):

From [jinja2 documentation](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.format)

> In most cases it should be more convenient and efficient to use the % operator or str.format().

So you can always write

```
{{ "{:>10}".format("test") }}
```

so as to keep the modern format string syntax, which is usually feature-richer than the printf-style formatting from the other answer.