# Spacing issue when render template through python

Tags: python-3.x, jinja2

I am getting weird spacing problem when I render my template using Python.

I have tried `ident()` and `trim()` but none yielded the desired output.

## Description: It matches the number of up interfaces with a defined interface in a class F5

```
loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.getcwd())
jenv=jinja2.Environment(loader=loader, trim_blocks=True, 
lstrip_blocks=False)
template=jenv.get_template('health_checks_temp.j2')

print("    +---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+\n    |                          F5 INTERFACE CHECKS                                    |\n    +---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+")
hostnames=['SSL222VP002400','ssl224vp222001','ssl224vp002400',] # Removed some of the items 
for i in hostnames:
    mgmt = ManagementRoot(i, 'USERNAME','PASSWORD')
    command='tmsh show net interface all | grep -i up | wc -l'
    cmd = "-c \'" + command + "\'"
    x = mgmt.tm.util.bash.exec_cmd('run', utilCmdArgs=cmd)
    data=(x.commandResult).split()
    if data[0] == getattr(F5,str(i)+'_interface'):
        print(template.render(dev_name=str(i), result='PASSED'))
    else:
        print(template.render(dev_name=str(i), result='FAILED'))
```

Template

```
 {{dev_name}}                                                {{result}}
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

-sh-4.1$

Expected

```
-sh-4.1$ python3.6 SECURITY-HEALTH-REPORT.py
    +---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    |                          F5 INTERFACE CHECKS                                    |
    +---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
     SSL222VP002400                                      PASSED
    +---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
     ssl224vp222001                                      PASSED
    +---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
     ssl224vp002400                                      PASSED
    +---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
     lbseks241                                           PASSED
    +---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
     fwlnnp152                                           PASSED
    +---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
     lbsekp242                                           PASSED
    +---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Actual

```
-sh-4.1$ python3.6 SECURITY-HEALTH-REPORT.py
    +---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    |                          F5 INTERFACE CHECKS                                    |
    +---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
     SSL222VP002400                                              PASSED
    +---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
     ssl224vp222001                                              PASSED
    +---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
     ssl224vp002400                                              PASSED
    +---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
     lbseks241                                           PASSED
    +---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
     fwlnnp152                                           PASSED
    +---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
     lbsekp242                                           PASSED
    +---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Hello, Dpac. Could you fix your code's indentation?

Comment: sorry , how do i do that ?

Comment: @DPac You can edit your post and then place 3 backticks before "for" and after "FAILED". I am guessing you cut and pasted proper python code but then added spaces before the "for" loop to make it part of the code. You could get rid of those spaces and add the backticks.

Comment: done finally ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your Jinja2 template does not adapt to the length of your variable. Since you have this one line in your file you could do it with python code. Considering you want a spacing of 30 between the `dev_name` and the result:

```
# With ljust
print(dev_name.ljust(30) + result)

# With format
print('{:<30}{}'.format(dev_name, result))

#For Python3 with f-string
print(f'{dev_name:<30}{result}')
```

If you want to stay with the Jinja2 template you can use the [builtin filter format](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#format) as it is said in this post: [Jinja2 Padding and Aligning Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45698629/jinja2-padding-and-aligning-strings)
It would look something like

```
 {{ "%-30s" | format(dev_name) }} {{result}}
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```